# typescript intellisense vscode error - payloadts(2345)

Tags: typescript

I have the following `fnIoTMqttPublishCommand` function using typescript:

```
const fnIoTMqttPublishCommand = async (params: {topic: string, payload: object}) => {
  try {
    console.log(' START fnIoTMqttPublishCommand')
    
    let topic = params.topic
    console.log(' topic: ', topic)
    
    let payload = params.payload
    console.log(' payload: ', payload)
    
    let sendParams = {
      topic: topic,
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
      qos: '0'
    }
    console.log(' sendParams: ', sendParams)
    
    const command = new PublishCommand(sendParams)
    console.log(' command: ', command)

    const response = await clientIoT.send(command)
    console.log(' response: ', response)

    return response
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(' fnIoTMqttPublishCommand - error.stack: ', error.stack)
    throw error.stack
  }
}
```

Then inside the `export handler` function I have the following:

```
export async function handler(event: any) {
  try {

    const jsb: object = {
      topic: "sdkv3/1",
      payload: {"att": 5}
    }
    
    const resp =  await fnIoTMqttPublishCommand(jsb)
        console.log(' resp', resp)

    return true 

  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
    const response = {
      statusCode: 500,
      error: err,
    };
    return response;
  }
}
```

My `typescript intellisense vscode` is showing the following error:

```
Argument of type 'object' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ topic: string; payload: object; }'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ topic: string; payload: object; }': topic, payloadts(2345)
const jsb: object
```

If I remove the object type (: object) form `const jsb: object` the error goes away:

```
const jsb = {
    topic: "sdkv3/1",
    payload: {"att": 5}
}
```

What is the error here?